# ShareKit Integration

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, sharekit

I was doing FB and Twitter integration of my application using the ShareKit. Which seems to be an awesome framework which reduces the development time a lot. However there seems to be lots of bugs/issues on the framework and looking on to that I discovered that there's a separate version maintained by the Open source community which is called ShareKit 2.0.

It available thorough the git repo and I download the framework as a ZIP bundle. But I can't compile this bundle the culprit seems to be it lacks FBConnect and JSON Kit files. AnyIdea why they haven't included these files ? / Will any version of FB would work with the latest Sharekit Framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the [installation wiki](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit) it looks like ShareKit includes it's dependencies as git submodules.

Since you are just downloading the zipped archive - this does not include these submodules, nor does it contain the information required to download them.

Your best bet is not to use the zipped archive, but to install it through git as the documentation says. Alternatively, you can download these dependencies yourself and add them to your project.

Comment: Thanks mate ! I'm a noob when it comes to git.

Answer (score 0):

Don't bother with ShareKit,  you'll encounter too many problems and their code will be out-of-date very quickly.  use Facebook's mobile api for Facebook.  HA!

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk

Comment: Any Idea why you say it's gonna be outdate ?

Comment: Change happens, so while everyone else is behind catching up on facebook's backend changes, Facebook themselves will be the first ones to update their class implementation.